# Execute command in background

Tags: go, concurrency, process, parallel-processing, background

I use the following code which is execute command of "npm install" , now while debug I see that the command is taking about 10..15 sec to execute (depend on how much module I've). what I want is that this command will execute in background and the program will continue.

```
cmd := exec.Command(name ,args...)
cmd.Dir = entryPath
```

In debug I see that to move to next line tass about 10..15 sec...

I’ve two questions in this:

1. How can I can do it? since I want to do something in parallel...
2. How can I know when it finishes? To provide additional logic which is related to this command i.e. after the `npm install` is done I need to
   do other stuff.

Comment: You need to run this in a goroutine and wait for it. Please see the [concurrency section of the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While in general you need goroutines to run something parallel (or more precisely *concurrent*), in case of running an external command or app in that manner does not require you to use goroutines (in fact, it's redundant).

This is because the [`exec.Cmd`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) used to run commands has a [`Cmd.Start()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start) method which starts the specified command but does not wait for it to complete. So you are free to do other stuff while it runs in the background, and when you need to wait for it to finish (and process its result), you may call [`Cmd.Wait()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Wait) (which will block and wait for the command to complete).

This is how it could look like:

```
cmd := exec.Command("npm", "install", "other_params")
cmd.Dir = entryPath

if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to start cmd: %v", err)
    return
}

// Do other stuff while cmd runs in background:
log.Println("Doing other stuff...")

// And when you need to wait for the command to finish:
if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Cmd returned error: %v", err)
}
```

In contrast to `Cmd.Start()`, there is [`Cmd.Run()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run) which starts the specified command and waits for it to complete, should you not need to run it in the "background". In fact `Cmd.Run()` is nothing more than a chaining of `Cmd.Start()` and `Cmd.Wait()` calls.

Note that when running in the "background", to get the output of the app, you can't call [`Cmd.Output()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output) or [`Cmd.CombinedOutput()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput) as they *run* then command and get its output (and you *already* started the command). If you need the output of the command, set a buffer to `Cmd.Stdout` which you can inspect / use after.

This is how it can be done:

```
cmd := exec.Command("npm", "install", "other_params")
cmd.Dir = entryPath
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
cmd.Stdout = buf

if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to start cmd: %v", err)
    return
}

// Do other stuff while cmd runs in background:
log.Println("Doing other stuff...")

// And when you need to wait for the command to finish:
if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Cmd returned error: %v", err)
    // You may decide to continue or return here...
}

fmt.Println("[OUTPUT:]", buf.String())
```

If you also want to capture the standard error stream of the app, you may / have to do the same with `Cmd.Stderr`. Tip: you may set the same buffer to `Cmd.Stdout` and `Cmd.Stderr`, and then you'll get the *combined output*, this is guaranteed as per doc:

> If Stdout and Stderr are the same writer, and have a type that can be compared with ==,
>   at most one goroutine at a time will call Write.

Comment: thanks a lot, intersting. can you please provide example with my context how would you use it ?

Comment: @tjholwik Sure, added an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot , give me 2 min and i’ll try it and let you know

Comment: @icza, this one is more appropriate. It implements channel inside. right?

Comment: @aerokite Go is open source, you can check its source how it's done: [`os/exec/exec.go`](https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go). Yes, it uses channels and other concurrency primitives in the background. If fact, `Cmd.Run()` is nothing more than calling `Cmd.Start()` and `Cmd.Wait()`.

Comment: @icza - thanks , before changing the code after putting the dir I use `out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()` to provide the output of the npm install , now I get error `exec: already started` , do you know how to avoid it or maybe use diffrent api to get the logs of the npm install command

Comment: @tjholwik You can't call `Cmd.Output()` as that runs the app and gets its output. If you need to get the output, then running the app in a separate goroutine (and calling `Cmd.Output()`) is easier.

Comment: Just to verify…so in this case I cannot use your provided solution (in case I somehow display the output in the logs) ?  to use the other solution is not redundent?

Comment: in case I didnt get it right can you please provide example how I can do it with your suggestion ?

Comment: @tjholwik Actually it's quite easy to "grab" the output: you can set a buffer prior to starting the app, which you can inspect / use after the app ended. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! , what about if I need to execute other logic when the process has finsihed on other package , can you give example please which fits your solution ?

Comment: @tjholwik There is no magic there. You do that as you would without the app execution. You have the app's output in `buf`, you may hand it over to anyone, including functions of other packages.

Comment: Thanks, im not talking about the buffer im talking about the `wait` which I should listen in `other package and execute it there` , can you provide some high level example (mock) how it should be done? thanks a lot! this is the only missing part on this.

Comment: @tjholwik It's unclear how your package and other packages waiting for the completion work together. If another package waits for it, pass the `cmd` to it and let it call its `Wait()` method. Or let that package execute the whole command. What you're asking is unclear, you should post it as a new question.

Comment: No I dont mean that two package is waiting , just other package wait to it to finish and then do something else… should I define the `cmd` as property in struct (global) and then `”require"` it in other package , is it ok ? or there is better approach ? thanks a lot!

Comment: @tjholwik My last comment still stands. It's unclear to me, and you should post it as a new question.

Comment: @icza very fine answer! Thanks for sharing the knowledge. I have one follow-up question - given concurrent calls of the go code which is calling the external script, will each concurrent call spawn a new process with the same script? like making the script also concurrent at the same time indirectly with different pid of each process?

Comment: @ahirnish Each `Cmd.Start()` launches a process with its own ID, and returns "immediately" (not waiting for the command to end). You may use a single goroutine to launch several commands, all will run parallel in their own process.

Comment: If you do un return after Cmd.Start(), the laucnhed application is stopped ?

Comment: @ipStack _What_ would make it stop?

Comment: if the GO application is closed after launching cmd.Start(), does npm continue to run?

Comment: @ipStack Returning from a function and terminating the app are 2 very different things. The latter may cause the child process to exit, but these are things you can easily try, so go ahead and try them.

Comment: I tried : some child process are stopped bu not all

Answer (score 9):

To run a method in parallel, you can use [goroutines](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines) and [channels](https://gobyexample.com/channels).

In goroutine, do your `exec.Command` operation. This will work in background.

And you can return information using channel from your goroutine.

And finally, you can check this value sent through channel. If you check immediately after calling `goroutine`, it will block until receives value from channel. So you need to check this after rest of the jobs that you want to do in parallel.

```
type Data struct {
    output []byte
    error  error
}

func runCommand(ch chan<- Data) {
    cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-la")
    data, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    ch <- Data{
        error:  err,
        output: data,
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan Data)

    // This will work in background
    go runCommand(c)

    // Do other things here

    // When everything is done, you can check your background process result
    res := <-c
    if res.error != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to execute command: ", res.error)
    } else {
        // You will be here, runCommand has finish successfuly
        fmt.Println(string(res.output))
    }
}
```

See in action: <kbd>[Play Ground](https://play.golang.org/p/gJqEXcmBMUf)</kbd>

Now, for OP's requirement how to implement this from another package.

> From comment: Yes I understand this . but if I need to register from other package res := <-c how it should be done properly

You can try this: <kbd>[Play Ground](https://play.golang.org/p/Avd4zXPzaiE)</kbd>. Check from another package `check`

> Note: this link will not build

Comment: Thanks 1+ , can I get some events and run this logic after , if so how i can register to it ? I want to get event and run the logic after the `npm install`

Comment: thanks , will check soon and let you know, some question, what does this do `ch <- Data{
        error:  err,
        output: data,
    }`  in addition, can I register to evnet in `other package` to act when this runCommand has finish ? if yes can you please provide example. thanks a lot!

Comment: Read this doc. You will get better idea: https://golangbot.com/channels/

Comment: it will ge great if you can give example in your post

Comment: Check you comments. `// You will be here`

Comment: Yes I understand this . but if I need to register from other package `res := <-c` how it should be done properly

Comment: I have added additional answer